# Diagnostics.Process - Dump output to file

Tags: c#

Hi I need to write the result of a mysqldump to a file with a standard windows commands.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "sample directory";
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "mysqldump";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-u root -pPassword --all-databases > db.sql";
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

But it doesn't write to file this way...
I don't want to read the output and then write it to file, since mysqldump output can become really big...
Any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try executing through cmd.exe and enquote the command to keep your program from gobbling up the redirect:

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.startinfo.Arguments = 
    "/c \"mysqldump -u root -pPassword --all-databases\" > db.sql"
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a lot of output you can use the `proc.OutputDataReceived` event, in the event handler just write the output to your file.

[Read the MSDN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much on similar lines, but written in VB.NET. Convert it and you should be good... [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rahulso/run-a-command-from-the-command-prompt-and-get-its-output-in-a-windows-application)

Answer (score 0):

For piped output you may need ShellExecute to be *true*. If that doesnt work, you may had to pipe it yourself (i.e. either handle the data events, or have an async read/write loop), but the size shouldn't matter since you should only be reading small chunks of it at any time.